# Migrating Google API Utility for deadline of March March 25, 2019

Tags: google-api

I received an email from the **Google Development Team** yesterday with this announcement:

> We are writing to let you know that the [JSON-RPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) and [Global HTTP batch](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/batch) endpoints will be deprecated on March 26, 2018, and no longer functional from March 25, 2019.

Their instruction was:

> Please migrate your applications for your affected projects listed below before March 25, 2019. We know that these changes have customer impact and have worked to make the transition steps as clear as possible. Detailed information on how to migrate your existing API Client Libraries can be found on the [Google Developers Blog post](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html).

I had a look through that article and it stated:

> [Google API Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/) have been regenerated to no longer make requests to the global HTTP batch endpoint. Clients using these libraries must upgrade to the latest version. Clients not using the Google API Client Libraries and/or making custom calls to the JSON-RPC endpoint or HTTP batch endpoint will need to make the changes outlined below.

In their email to me they specifically stated that my project will be affected. It is a Visual Basic .Net application that works with the [V3 Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/). I have alsp been making use of **batch** facilities.

At the moment I am using Google APIs version *1.29.2* but I see there is a newer version:

[image: Nuget Package Updates]

It is really not clear to me what I need to do in order to become compliant with this adjustment? The aforementioned blog post encouraged us to tag questions here with `google-api` if we needed help.

Help! Thanks!

---

Here is an example of how I am using batch requests:

```
Dim oBatchRequest = New Google.Apis.Requests.BatchRequest(m_Service)
...
...
Dim oTaskDelete = oBatchRequest.ExecuteAsync()
oTaskDelete.Wait()
```

It it now clear to me which version of the API libraries use this newer approach that they emailed me about. If it helps, the **scopes** I am using are:

```
m_Scopes.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar "
             "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/ "
             "https://mail.google.com/")
```

---

I have just updated the packages from `v1.29.2` to `v1.32.2` and did a full compile and had no errors. I did a test sync and it looks like it is working.

My Inno Setup script currently installs these files on the users computer:

```
; Google Calendar Interface v3
Source: "Google.Apis.Auth.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "Google.Apis.Core.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "Google.Apis.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "Google.Apis.PlatformServices.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "Google.GData.Client.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "Google.GData.Contacts.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "Google.GData.Extensions.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "GoogleAuthandSync.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "GoogleAuthandSync.exe.config"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "Newtonsoft.Json.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "System.Net.Http.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "Zlib.Portable.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

My folder actually has these files:

```
D:\My Programs\2017\GoogleAuthandSync\GoogleAuthandSync\bin\Release>dir *.dll
 Volume in drive D is DATA
 Volume Serial Number is A8B0-A5C6

 Directory of D:\My Programs\2017\GoogleAuthandSync\GoogleAuthandSync\bin\Release

26/04/2016  12:16         2,236,416 BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll
08/02/2018  11:32           105,472 Google.Apis.Auth.dll
08/02/2018  11:32             5,120 Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices.dll
26/03/2018  08:38            89,600 Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.dll
08/02/2018  11:32            67,072 Google.Apis.Core.dll
08/02/2018  11:32            71,680 Google.Apis.dll
08/02/2018  11:32             4,096 Google.Apis.PlatformServices.dll
25/06/2013  11:24           212,992 Google.GData.Client.dll
25/06/2013  11:33            29,184 Google.GData.Contacts.dll
25/06/2013  11:27            90,112 Google.GData.Extensions.dll
08/03/2017  20:26           276,480 log4net.dll
18/06/2017  13:57           653,824 Newtonsoft.Json.dll
13/08/2013  01:19            27,296 System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
13/08/2013  01:19         1,172,568 System.Data.dll
13/08/2013  01:19            63,064 System.Net.dll
05/09/2017  14:54           197,984 System.Net.Http.dll
19/02/2015  21:10            22,232 System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll
19/02/2015  21:10            21,720 System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll
05/11/2016  05:57            39,872 System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll
05/11/2016  05:57            23,480 System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll
05/11/2016  05:57            22,816 System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll
05/09/2017  14:54            38,872 System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll
13/08/2013  01:19           921,688 System.XML.dll
13/08/2013  01:19            43,112 System.Xml.Linq.dll
22/06/2015  09:00            81,920 Zlib.Portable.dll
              25 File(s)      6,518,672 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  717,216,362,496 bytes free
```

So these look extra:

```
26/04/2016  12:16         2,236,416 BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll
08/03/2017  20:26           276,480 log4net.dll
13/08/2013  01:19            27,296 System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
13/08/2013  01:19         1,172,568 System.Data.dll
13/08/2013  01:19            63,064 System.Net.dll
05/11/2016  05:57            39,872 System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll
05/11/2016  05:57            23,480 System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll
05/11/2016  05:57            22,816 System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll
05/09/2017  14:54            38,872 System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll
```

Do I have to deplay them?

Comment: Please focus on a single question per post - the part about batching is entirely separate from the part about which DLLs you need to deploy. You should ask a new question with the deployment part, and remove it from this question. (But I'd be surprised if those are *new* since 1.29.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only making calls to a single API (Calendar v3) then your batched requests will be homogenous and you should not need to change your code, other than to upgrade your client library.

Comment: So the v1.32.2 library? That is OK to use for this "change"? Will my code need any changes?

Comment: Yes, the latest version (1.32.2) should be right.  I can't tell you definitively about your code but based on this thread you should not need to change it. If you have any issues please raise them here.  Thanks!

Comment: I have just updated my question and appreciate your clarification.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I can't answer this one so checking for you.  Standby.

Answer (score 0):

In case you were creating \Google_Http_Batch objects directly in PHP, you should follow this [comment](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/commit/074daa249365e2401164cadb4f88a25fa65db063#diff-0ec1fd118f1515e4f1c6a88185c6a547):

```
$service = new \Google_Service_Calendar();
$batch = $service->createBatch();
```